# Scrapy commands yield 'bash: cd: too many arguments'

Tags: bash, scrapy, python-3.7, debian-buster

I am having problem executing scrapy commands.

I'm trying to create new scrapy project, it used to work, but now it does not. I think I made some changes on the system (Debian 10) and broke it somehow. I think this is not scrapy problem, but something with virtual env.

I created and activated venv, and inside of it I installed scrapy using `pip`. I verified that scrapy is  installed by using `which` command.
When I execute the command `scrapy startproject myproject` I get

> bash: cd: too many arguments

Same happens if I try to run one of my old spiders by using command `scrapy crawl spider123`

The interesting part is that **it works** if I run the commands from within the bash script :

spider123.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/scrapy/spider123/env/bin/activate
scrapy crawl spider123
```

and execute it by using command `./spider123.sh`

Comment: Do you have an alias or function that shadows the built-in `cd`, which the script would not inherit?

Comment: @chepner I'm not sure, can you help me find out?

Comment: What's the output of `type cd`?

Comment: the output is: 'cd is a shell builtin'

Comment: Try `type cd` after activating your virtual env

Comment: I tried both, and both giving same output

Comment: When I type 'scrapy' outside of venv, the current directory gets moved into one of my old scrapy projects, which is very weird. I removed globally installed scrapy.